# How can I declare a route and a controller method that explicitly expect two query parameters like this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

I am pretty new in **Laravel** and I have the following problem.

I have to declare a route that handle requests like this:

```
http://laravel.dev/activate?email=myemail@gmail.com&token=eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc
```

So this URL have to mantein this format (**activate** as resource and 2 query parameters in the form **?email** and **&token**. This is not a REST URI. I need to use it in this way).

I need a route and a controller method that handle this kind of request.

I know that I can do something like this:

1) Into the **routes/web.php** file I declare a rout like this

```
Route::get('/activate','MyController@myMethod');
```

2) Into **MyController** I declare this method:

```
public function myMethod(Request $request) {

    if(Input::has('email') && Input::has('token')) {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $token= $request->input('token');

        // DO SOMETHING USING $email AND $token
    }
    else {
        // SHOW ERROR PAGE
    }
}
```

But onestly I find it pretty horrible. I came from Java and using Spring framework I can specify in the mapping between the URL and the controller method that a method handle a request toward a resource and that to be handled some specific query paramer have to be passed. Otherwise (if these parameter are not present the HTTP GET request is not handled by the controller method).

I know that in Laravel I can do something like this using **REST** form of my URL, I think something like this:

For the route mapping:

```
Route::get('/activate/{email}/{token}', [ 'uses' => 'ActivationController@activate', 'as' => 'activate' ]);
```

And then the controller method will be something like this:

```
public function activate($email, $token) {
    // $email would be 'myemail@gmail.com'
    // $token would be 'eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc'
    // do stuff...
}
```

But I can't use this kind of URI in this case (as specified the URL pattern have to be in the format:

> http://laravel.dev/activate?**email=myemail@gmail.com**&**token=eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc**

So I desire do something like this with this kind of URI. I don't wont to pass the **Request $request** object to my controller method and then extract the parameters from it but I want to have a controller method signature like this:

```
public function activate($email, $token) {
```

in which if all the expected parameters are not passed simply the request will not handled by this controller.

I prefer do it because for me is a neater approach (reading the controller signature another developer immediately know that this method is expecting).

And also because I want that malformed parameters are not handled by the method (so I can avoid to handle error cases like: the user not pass the 2 parameters).

How can I do something like this in Laravel? (if it is possible...)

Comment: You can either create middleware that does checking (overkill), and custom [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#creating-form-requests) that does validation so without valid parameters your controllers method is not hit.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a strange request, because it defies a more traditional use of Laravel routing practices, but this should work for you:

In `routes.php` (Laravel < 5.3) or `web.php` (Laravel 5.4+):

```
Route::get('/activate', [ 'as' => 'activate', function()
{
    return app()->make(App\Http\Controllers\ActivateController::class)->callAction('activate', $parameters = [ 'email' => request()->email, 'token' => request()->token ]);
}]);
```

So we are instantiating the ActivateController class and calling the method 'activate' which is the first argument, then supplying a list of parameters the method receives in the form of an array.

```
public function activate($email, $token)
{
    echo "Email: $email"; // myemail@gmail.com
    echo "Token: $token"; // eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc
    // do stuff
}
```

Now, provided you go to `http://laravel.dev/activate?email=myemail@gmail.com&token=eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc` `$email` and `$token` will be the respective key query parameters.

Now, as for validating to ensure that data is present. You have to add another argument to your `activate()` method, unless you want to do it inline.

**The best practice way:**

Run `php artisan make:request ActivateRequest`

A new file called ActivateRequest will be created in `app\Http\Requests`. Open it up and make sure your `authorize()` method returns `true` like so:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Next, in the `rules()` method there is an array. Add the following:

```
return [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'token' => 'required',
];
```

If you want to supply your own validation messages to these rules, add a method below `rules()` called `messages()` Like so:

```
public function messages()
{
     return [
        'email.required' => 'You must supply an email address.',
        'email.email' => 'That email is address is not valid.',
        'token.required' => 'Please supply a token.',
     ];
}
```

Then, back in `ActivateController` pull in your new FormRequest class at the top `use App\Http\Requests\ActivateRequest;` and use it in the method like so:

```
activate($email, $token, ActivateRequest $request) {
    ...
```

Now, your request will be validated and you don't even have to use the `$request` variable.

**The inline (not so best practice way)**

If you are *dead set* on not having an extra argument in your method, you can validate data in the controller like so:

First, bring in the `Validator` class at the top. `use Validator;`.

```
public function activate($email, $token)
{
    $validationMessages = [
        'email.required' => 'You must supply an email address.',
        'email.email' => 'That email is address is not valid.',
        'token.required' => 'Please supply a token.',
     ];

    $validation = Validator::make(request()->toArray(), [
        'email.required' => 'You must supply an email address.',
        'email.email' => 'That email is address is not valid.',
        'token.required' => 'Please supply a token.',
    ], $validationMessages);

    if ( $validation->fails() )
    {
       return 'Sorry, there was a problem with your request';
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To me it's sad that query parameters are so neglected in PHP frameworks. i found this answer after an hour of searching whether or not Laravel *does* validate query params because the docs don't have much to say and most search results for validation are for REST routes. Thanks for this response, which not only instructs how to solve the issue but verifies the query inputs ARE validated. *Phew!*